# Hotspot compiler not generating aes-ni instructions

Tags: java, cryptography, aes, jvm-hotspot

I want to see hardware aes-ni instructions with the HotSpot compiler. I'm using OpenJDK version "1.8.0_191"

I have written a Java program for this purpose, and ran it with this command:

```
java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+UseAES -XX:+UseAESIntrinsics -XX:+PrintAssembly  AES > assembly.txt
```

But I'm unable to see hardware aes-ni (for ex: aesenc) instructions.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7184394 says jdk suports aes-ni instructions.

I have ensured that the method is getting compiled and enabling +XX:PrintIntrinsics shown below:

```
@ 41 com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCrypt::decryptBlock (3852 bytes) (intrinsic) @ 41  
com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCrypt::encryptBlock (953 bytes) (intrinsic) @ 12   
java.lang.Math::addExact (26 bytes) (intrinsic) @ 572  
java.lang.System::arraycopy (0 bytes) (intrinsic) @ 41   
com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCrypt::decryptBlock (3852 bytes) (intrinsic) @ 41  
com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCrypt::encryptBlock (953 bytes) (intrinsic) @ 41  
com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCrypt::decryptBlock (3852 bytes) (intrinsic) @ 41  
com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCrypt::encryptBlock (953 bytes) (intrinsic)
```

Can someone please help on this?
Thank You

```
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AES {

    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;
    private static byte[] key;

    public static void setKey(String myKey)
    {
        MessageDigest sha = null;
        try {
            key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String secret)
    {
        try
        {
            setKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Please post entire runnable code for your class `AES` so we can reproduce it. The assembly would only show up in the code that calls AESCrypt directly (so somewhere inside the code for the crypto library) - not in your AES class.

Comment: You will need the 64 bit server VM for AES-NI to be available. Are you sure that AES-NI is not used? It says (intrinsic) in comments, and that could point to AES-NI intrinsics - or am I missing something?

Comment: Erwin Bolwidt. Thank you for the reply. posted the full code.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes Thank you . grep aes in the printed assembly does not show me anything. I've seen the assembly code emitted for the intrinsic and couldn't find any aes instruictions.